# Error importing a user js file using electron-builder

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I have an electron application with main process as follows:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, dialog} = require('electron');
const path = require('path')
let logConfig = require('./js/loggConfig.js');
....
```

This executes perfectly when run directly from terminal.
But when I package this project using electron-builder, and install it on another machine (Windows 10), I get the following error while launching the app:
`Error: Cannot find module '.js/loggConfig.js'`

How do I resolve this?

Here is how my `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "ABCD",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "...",
  "author": "abcd <abcd@gmail.com>",
  "homepage": "http://www.abcd.com",
  "main": "main_electron.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "yourappid",
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 110,
          "y": 150
        },
        {
          "x": 240,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "deb"
      ],
      "category": "Video"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "NSIS",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico",
      "extraResources": [
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-context-menu": "^0.9.1",
    "electron-log": "^2.2.13",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "xmlbuilder": "^9.0.4",
    "zip-folder": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.7.9",
    "electron-builder": "^19.49.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved the issue changing the build configuration.

- Setting `asar` to `false`.
- Setting `asarUnpack` to export all the `asar` content with `"**/*"`.

```json
     "build": {
        "appId": "app.node.electron",
        "productName": "app electron",
        "asar":false,
        "asarUnpack":[
          "**/*"
        ],
        "directories": {
          "output": "release"
        },
        "win": {
          "publisherName": "app electron",
          "icon": "icon.png",
          "target": [
            "nsis"
          ]
        },
      },
```